# Expected people to get atleast m heads in n flips

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have `k` people flipping coin `n` times each. How many of these `k` people will get atleast `m` heads each. I am not sure how to model this problem. Here, obviously `m < n`.

Comment: What do you mean by "how many"?  Somewhere between $0$ and $k$.

Comment: Compute the probability for a single person. Then use the binomial distribution.

Comment: @saulspatz yes between `0` and `k`

Comment: @lulu are you saying something like $(C^{n}_{m} 0.5^{m} (1-0.5)^{n-m} + C^{n}_{m+1} 0.5^{m+1} (1-0.5)^{n-m-1} + ... + C^{n}_{n} 0.5^{0} (1-0.5)^{n}) * k $?

Comment: Are you asking for the expected number?  What do you mean by "how many"?

Comment: @Gerry  Yes.  And of course it helps that the $H$ and $T$ probabilities coincide, so this is just the sum of binomial ocefficeints times $.5^n$.

Comment: @saulspatz yes the expected number.

Comment: @lulu unfortunately that does not match the answer.

Comment: Then @lulu's already told you how to do it.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @saulspatz I tried to do as shown in 4th comment by me but it doesn't give the correct answer.

Comment: Well, depending on the size of $m,n$ (both absolute and relative) you could use a normal approximation, or you could sum the probabilities of getting  $<m$ and subtract.  But absent more information I don't see anything wrong with the given sum.

Comment: Can you show us what you did and what the "correct" answer is?  There's nothing more to say with more information.

Comment: @lulu I have `k=1000`, `n=21` and `m=17` and answer is 4.

Comment: I get $3.59869$  Is it possible they are rounding to the nearest integer?

Comment: @lulu exactly that is what I was getting